# MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME() returns null with last_update column of sakila.actor

Tags: mysql, timezone

The actor table in the salika sample schema defines column last_update as a timestamp. I want to render that column using JSON_ARRAY in ISO8601 format. - First shouldn't that be the default rendering for JSON_ARRAY.

From reading the documentation and comments on this website and others it appears that the answer is to use FROM_UNXTIME with an output mask that generates ISO8601 Format.

Unfortunately  FROM_UNIXTIME() appears to always return NULL on my database

```
mysql> select current_timestamp();
+---------------------+
| current_timestamp() |
+---------------------+
| 2018-10-03 17:15:03 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select from_unixTime(current_timestamp())
-> ;
+------------------------------------+
| from_unixTime(current_timestamp()) |
+------------------------------------+
| NULL                               |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I suspect this may be caused by the fact that I have not installed the timezone configuration files.. However when I try that I get...

```
mysql -u root -p****** sys  <timezone_posix.sql
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'sys.time_zone' doesn't exist
```

Sure I've missed something obvious here....

Comment: OK, I fixed the issue with loading the timezone configuration information, the target database for this operation is 'mysql', not 'sys'. The operation completed successfully but after stopping the restarting the service I still have the problem with from_unixtime() returning null..

Comment: OK now am I getting myself confused... FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp()) returns the expected results. But unix_timestamp() on it own retuns an epoch value, which makes sense, to it would appear that FROM_UNIX time expects an epoch. If I have column of type timestamp, such as the aforementioned last_update column it appears it cannot be used with FROM_UNIXTIME,

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()));
```

As [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) says, function `FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp[,format])` only accept parameter as a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, but not a `TIMESTAMP`.

Luckily, there's a function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` transforming various types such as `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` and so on into `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. So call `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` first, and then `FROM_UNIXTIME(

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the end...

```
select json_array("actor_id","first_name","last_name",DATE_FORMAT(convert_tz("last_update", @@session.time_zone, '+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%dT%T%fZ')) "json" from "sakila"."actor"
```

/

which gives

```
 [
            1,
            "PENELOPE",
            "GUINESS",
            "2006-02-15T12:34:33000000Z"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "NICK",
            "WAHLBERG",
            "2006-02-15T12:34:33000000Z"
        ]
```